# How can i loop this function also adding a link to replace appended images

Tags: jquery

Not having any idea what i'm doing with jQuery this has turned into a quest , but i'm getting closer....

I am running this function to replace team names with team icons , the server has a database set up that corresponds names and icons using fid_0001 to fid_0096 , that is the min and max range that each table can have.

```
var name = franchiseDatabase['fid_0001'].name;
$('#brief_standings , #livescoring_summary ').find('td').filter(function() { return $(this).text() == name; })
.html( '<img src="' + franchiseDatabase['fid_0001'].icon + '" />' );
```

How can i wrap each image i'm inserting with a link ?
How do i loop this, so i don't have to write this out 96 times with all instances of:
fid_0001 , fid_0002 , fid_003 etc etc to fid_0096 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple loop would be:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 96;  i++) {

    var fdb = null;

    if ( i < 10 ) {
        fdb = franchiseDatabase['fid_000' + i];
    } else {
        fdb = franchiseDatabase['fid_00' + i];
    }

    $('#brief_standings , #livescoring_summary ')
    .find('td').filter(function() { return $(this).text() == fdb.name; })
    .html( '<a href="YOUR_MAGICAL_LINK"><img src="' + fdb.icon + '" /></a>' );
}
```

Comment: this is working beautifully !  Can you edit to show where i can add a link the the image as well please ? Thanks

Comment: there you go :) (don't forget to replace "YOUR_MAGICAL_LINK" with the actual link it needs to refer to).

Answer (score 2):

Hmm...assuming `franchiseDatabase` holds all the names you want to change:

```
for (var key in franchiseDatabase) {
    var name = franchiseDatabase[key].name;
    $('#brief_standings , #livescoring_summary ').find('td').filter(function() { 
        return $(this).text() == name; 
    }).html( '<a href="xx"><img src="' + franchiseDatabase[key].icon + '" /></a>' );
}
```

I added a link to the HTML append, not sure if this is what you're looking for or not.